# Mouse_down event not being triggered in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've got some code written is AS3. My aim is to have the MainTimeline stage clicked and to run the `trace()` within function `runDraw()`. At the moment, the MOUSE_DOWN event is never being triggered and I can't figure it out.

**Code update**:

```
package circles
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Circles extends Sprite
    {
        var circCentre:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var circOuter:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var point:Sprite = new Sprite();

        trace("Class stuff initilized");

        function Circles():void
        {   
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, runDraw);
            trace("Constructor done");
        }

        function runDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("runDraw(e)");
            // centre circle draw and add to timeline
            circCentre.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000);
            circCentre.graphics.beginFill(0xFF6600);
            circCentre.x = e.stageX;
            circCentre.y = e.stageY;
            circCentre.graphics.drawCircle(e.stageX, e.stageY, 100);
            circCentre.graphics.endFill();
            this.addChild(circCentre);
            trace("mc.addChild(circCentre)");

            // smaller outer circle
            circCentre.addChild(circOuter);
            // attach to parent;
            circOuter.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xDD2211);
            circOuter.graphics.beginFill(0x66FF00);
            circOuter.x = 200;
            circOuter.y = e.stageY;
            circOuter.graphics.drawCircle(200, e.stageY, 50);
            circOuter.graphics.endFill();

            // the draw point;
            circOuter.addChild(point);
            point.graphics.moveTo(5, 0);
            point.graphics.lineTo(5, 10);
            point.graphics.moveTo(0, 5);
            point.graphics.lineTo(10, 5);
            point.x = 50;
            point.y = 90;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotationDraw);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, finish);
        }

        public function rotationDraw(e:Event):void
        {
            circCentre.rotation++;
            circOuter.rotation++;
        }

        public function finish(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotationDraw);
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works (I have modified your class code).

**Timeline**

```
var c:Circles = new Circles(stage);
addChild(c);
```

**Class file**

```
// removed package name for testing
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Circles extends Sprite
    {
        var circCentre:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var circOuter:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var point:Sprite = new Sprite();

        var _stage:Stage;

        // shouldn't really have trace statements out here
        trace("Class stuff initilized");

        function Circles(stage:Stage):void
        {   
            _stage = stage;

            _stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, runDraw);
            trace("Constructor done");
        }

        function runDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("runDraw(e)");
            // centre circle draw and add to timeline
            circCentre.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000);
            circCentre.graphics.beginFill(0xFF6600);
            circCentre.x = e.stageX;
            circCentre.y = e.stageY;
            circCentre.graphics.drawCircle(e.stageX, e.stageY, 100);
            circCentre.graphics.endFill();
            _stage.addChild(circCentre);
            trace("mc.addChild(circCentre)");

            // smaller outer circle
            circCentre.addChild(circOuter);
            // attach to parent;
            circOuter.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xDD2211);
            circOuter.graphics.beginFill(0x66FF00);
            circOuter.x = 200;
            circOuter.y = e.stageY;
            circOuter.graphics.drawCircle(200, e.stageY, 50);
            circOuter.graphics.endFill();

            // the draw point;
            circOuter.addChild(point);
            point.graphics.moveTo(5, 0);
            point.graphics.lineTo(5, 10);
            point.graphics.moveTo(0, 5);
            point.graphics.lineTo(10, 5);
            point.x = 50;
            point.y = 90;
            _stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotationDraw);
            _stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, finish);
        }

        public function rotationDraw(e:Event):void
        {
            circCentre.rotation++;
            circOuter.rotation++;
        }

        public function finish(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotationDraw);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AHH! So needed to pass the stage by reference from the Timeline... Awesome dude, thanks!

Comment: No drama's. I'm glad it helped - I like the effect by the way

Comment: Heh thanks, it's not come out right just yet, got another day or two to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

The mc MovieClip has no dimensions, so there is no hitarea for the `MOUSE_DOWN` event to work. You need to draw this hit area. Try this:

```
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,0);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,800,600);//change 800,600 to whatever is your stage size
```

Comment: I copied your code into the constructor... still no Event being dispatched unfortunately.

Comment: add mc.graphics.endFill(); after the drawRect just for good measure. and then addchild(mc)

Comment: Yup got all that, still no joy :( I hate it when there's no obvious reason.

Comment: The whole thing about using a sprite or mc as a container just depends on what you need it for. It is fine to use them as a container though. I will work up a small prototype and you can fix from there.

Comment: @AlexW From Chris' answer I see you actualy meant the timeline. I was under the impression it was the document class you were writing :P